# Identifying the data structure

Tags: c#, azure-cognitive-services

I am currently using the Microsoft Azure Personalizer API, and trying to read my data from an excel file. I don't understand what, this data structure provided as a sample in the documentation is.

I am new to c# and am guessing it is a dictionary of dictionaries. How can I print the data inside too?

```
static IList<RankableAction> GetActions()
    {
        IList<RankableAction> actions = new List<RankableAction>
        {
            new RankableAction
            {
                Id = "pasta",
                Features =
                new List<object>() { new { taste = "salty", spiceLevel = "medium" }, new { nutritionLevel = 5, cuisine = "italian" } }
            },

            new RankableAction
            {
                Id = "ice cream",
                Features =
                new List<object>() { new { taste = "sweet", spiceLevel = "none" }, new { nutritionalLevel = 2 } }
            },

            new RankableAction
            {
                Id = "juice",
                Features =
                new List<object>() { new { taste = "sweet", spiceLevel = "none" }, new { nutritionLevel = 5 }, new { drink = true } }
            },

            new RankableAction
            {
                Id = "salad",
                Features =
                new List<object>() { new { taste = "salty", spiceLevel = "low" }, new { nutritionLevel = 8 } }
            }
        };

        foreach(RankableAction s in actions)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }

        return actions;
    }
```

Comment: Its a List of `RankableAction`, `RankableAction` is a custom class which contains `Id` and `Features` as a properties

Comment: Nothing that complex. It is a List (array that can change it's size) of `RankableAction` instances. Useage is very similar to a `RankableAction[]`;

Comment: The `Features` is a list of anonymous objects with varying properties.  Basically it's a bunch of unstructured data.

Comment: Now RankableAction happens to have two fields or properties: `Id ` wich is a simple string. And features, wich is itself a `List[object]`. Now the entries in those Lists seem to be anonymous types. That part seems to be unesssarily complex. I can think of around 3 ways to write it better readable, but of course that requires a lot more writing. And synce they are Anonamous types, that means he had to make the list accept Object. Wich is around the thing you should never put into a Generic List as type.

Comment: How would I print out the instance "actions"?

Comment: As you are new to C#, I doubt you will be able to read this. **I** have issues reading that and it is not my first rodeo. Even the type and allocation of `actions` is pointlessly complex. He defined the variables as the Interface that all Lists implement to assign a fully fledged List. Wich is entirely unessesary at this point. Usually you leave those kinds of cast for cases where some code only accepts ILists and do not bother with it.

Comment: @sabyasachisahoo Printing out the Id is pretty simple. `Console.WriteLine(s.Id);` is the only changed needed. The Features is the part where printing out is not easy at all. You definitely need a subloop going over `s.Features` and hope you can deal with those Anonymous types.

Comment: Using these print statements, I get the following output.

    foreach (RankableAction s in actions)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s.Id);
                foreach (object i in s.Features)
                    Console.WriteLine(i);
            }

pasta
{ taste = salty, spiceLevel = medium }
{ nutritionLevel = 5, cuisine = italian }
ice cream
{ taste = sweet, spiceLevel = none }
{ nutritionalLevel = 2 }
juice
{ taste = sweet, spiceLevel = none }
{ nutritionLevel = 5 }
{ drink = True }
salad
{ taste = salty, spiceLevel = low }
{ nutritionLevel = 8 }

Comment: But i still don't understand how the individual objects are tied together. Does action.features create one lists or multiple for each action.ID?

Comment: The collections of data (list, array, whatever you want to call it) are JSON objects defined here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/personalizer/concepts-features.